# ListBox inside ListBox and selectedItem / Events

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have now been stuck at this for some time so I though to ask the experts here.

First the XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Tap="Some_Tap" SelectionChanged="Some_SelectionChanged">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- the panel which covers a complete list item -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                <!-- start and end time for the travel route-->
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                    <!-- some textblock items, removed to keep this simple -->
                                </Grid>

                                <!-- list box for images -->
                                <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Thumbs}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,50">
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="{Binding FontWeightForText}">
                                                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}"/>
                                                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                                </TextBlock>

                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                                </ListBox>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

So as you can see from the XAML I have a ListBox inside the data template of another ListBox. I have Tap & SelectionChanged events wired.

Problem:

1. I can't click on the area covered by the inner list box, the tap or selection changed events for the outer list box are not fired for the outerlistbox.
2. I could wire tap and selection changed events for the inner listbox as well, but then how would I know which item in the outerlistbox this innerlistbox belongs to, selectedindex.

help ??

-A

Comment: Solved by changing the XAML slightly, no C# code was changed XAML. Inner ListBox was changed to ItemsControl, as answered by Ku6opr below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need items selection in the list, use `ItemsControl` instead (for inner list in this situation)

Comment: So this worked very well, I was doubtful about it though. I just changed the inner ListBox to ItemsControl  ( changed the tags in XAML ) and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the inner ListBox control `IsEnabled = false` and the Tap events of the outer will start to execute!

Comment: I could do that, but then because the ListBox has a different template for disabled mode the listbox looks ugly. If I go with this solution than I need to define a new style for the disabled mode too.

Comment: True, but you can just go ahead and just edit the ListBox template alltogether and remove the visualstate for the disabled state! :)