# Scrolling on List of User Controls with Listboxes inside in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a list of User Controls in a screen in my WP7 app. Each User control has a header text block, a listbox and a button. And the listbox in the usercontrol will have it's height bound so as to show the complete height. Now when I try to scroll the list of UserControls, the manipulation events are being consumed by the ListBox inside.

One solution I can come up with is adding all the controls in a single ListBox and removing the UserControl. This might be weird. But that is my only option as of now. And also this is letting the ListBox item's height being recalculated. which gives a jumpy effect.

Is there better solution? Maybe we can disable the manipulation events on the listbox and allowing only tap event on the ListBox items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to disable inner list scrolling. Set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` in xaml.

To disable manipulations on inner list, you should use `ItemsControl` instead of `ListBox`. Recent question about this: [ListBox inside ListBox and selectedItem / Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903594/listbox-inside-listbox-and-selecteditem-events/9908025#9908025)

Comment: Thanks, it is working. My bad, I should have searched better.